# Who is the CPU or FPGA maker in this picture?

Tags: identification

For the life of me I am unable to find or determine who makes the chip with the label shown in the image:

[image]

HLi, HL Inc, KLi?

Comment: I've traced it for better contrast 
http://i49.tinypic.com/10i9ouc.png

Comment: Are you absolutely sure what kind of chip it is? Are there sites that let you search by pin numbers?

Answer (score 7):

former Huawei company HiSilicon http://www.hisilicon.com/

Answer (score 5):

I don't recognize the logo.  Most likely the chip is an [ASIC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASIC).  There's only a couple of [FPGA manufacturers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FPGA#Major%5Fmanufacturers) (Xilinx and Altera are the big ones).  Likewise, there aren't a lot of CPU manufacturers.  On the other hand, there are LOTS of ASIC vendors.

If you could provide an image of the entire chip (size, form-factor, part numbers) it might be possible to better identify it (and therefore the manufacturer).  If the only thing printed on the chip is the logo, then that's more evidence in favor of an ASIC -- since it's an application-specific chip, there's no need to provide part numbers (since it's not for sale) or documentation.

Answer (score 3):

is it this group?
http://www.hli.com.my/Corp_Info/Semiconductor/semiconductor.asp

Comment: It looks like their chips are branded by a subsidiary company: http://www.hli.com.my/Corp_Info/Semiconductor/Carsem/Carsem.asp

Answer (score 2):

A quick googling turned up a useful site

http://how-to.wikia.com/wiki/How_to_identify_integrated_circuit_%28chip%29_manufacturers_by_their_logos

.. but sadly these are indexed by name, so you have to guess the first letter of your logo to narrow things to a reasonable number to look through.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another page full of IC logos:

http://www.advanced-tech.com/ic_logos/ic_logos.htm

However I didn't see your logo (but maybe I didn't look hard enough)